# Angular disable click event for mat-button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a column with buttons in a mat-table . Based on a value, I check if the button should be enabled or disabled and works fine. The problem is that if the user click on a disabled button, it will get an error. How I can disable the click event for a disabled button?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="download">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>download</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-button  [disabled]="isDisabled(element.status)" (click)="download(element.value)"> download </mat-button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Specify the error you're getting

Comment: I'm getting an error from the backend. Because if the button is disabled, the click event shouldn't download something.

Comment: As a workaround, in your download function, you can start with `if(isDisabled(element.status)) return`

Comment: If the button clicked event is firing that means button it is not disabled at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="download">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>download</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-button  [disabled]="isDisabled(element.status)" (click)="!isDisabled(element.status) && download(element.value)"> download </mat-button>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```